# How to link against CoreGraphics framework from swiftc on command line

Tags: swift, core-graphics

**I am writing a command line program and have to use the CoreGraphics library**

**How do I go about linking the CoreGraphics framework when using the native swiftc command?**

A bit of background just to explain the rationale:

1. I am trying to execute MPSMatrix operations (i.e. compute operations) using the Apple MPS Library.
2. I like to develop using the native command line when I am writing very simple experiments to avoid getting bogged down in the toolsets (e.g. xcode, swift packages)
3. The apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/1433401-mtlcreatesystemdefaultdevice)   states that you need to link the CoreGraphics framework to use MPS even in a simple command line tool
4. The swiftc command seems to bring in Foundation, Metal etc. automatically but appears not to be able to automatically find and link the CoreGraphics framework.

The program I am working with at the moment is:

```
import CoreGraphics
import Metal
import Foundation
import Accelerate
import MetalPerformanceShaders

guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else {
    fatalError( "Failed to get the system's default Metal device." )
}

let N = 1000000

// Create a Metal buffer of length N
let buffer = device.makeBuffer(length: N * MemoryLayout<Float32>.size)

// Create a vector descriptor
let descriptor = MPSVectorDescriptor(length: N, dataType: .float32)

// Create a vector with descriptor
let vector = MPSVector(buffer: buffer!, descriptor: descriptor)
```

This fails on the MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() call at the moment, which I assume is because I haven't linked the CoreGraphics framework - so that's the question - how to link it from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

OK So I have continued to experiment and evntually just copied the command structure for clang. The (very simple answer) is:

```
swiftc -framework CoreGraphics myprog.swift
```